# How to prevent sssd package from modifying nsswitch.conf

Tags: apt, sudo, sssd

We are running sssd on a number of Xenial servers to authenticate against Active Directory.

Upon installation, the `sssd` package added `sss` to most lines in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` as documented in https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html#sssd-ad-nsswitch . Regrettably, this includes the `sudoers` line, which results in an error message

```
problem with defaults entries
```

being mailed to the root account for every single use of `sudo`, which in our case includes an important number of `cron` jobs resulting in a **lot** of mails.

This is easily fixed by manually removing `sss` from that line again. However, each update of the `sssd` package re-adds that unwanted entry, triggering another flood of mails before we manually remove it again.

How can we avoid that?

Comment: File a bug report.

Comment: Ah here it is: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sssd/+bug/1249777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution on the bug report is to [disable sudo support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sssd/+bug/1249777/comments/11). From the link:

> As a workaround that doesn't require changing `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, you can also explicitely disable sudo support for your sssd domain :

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam, sudo

[mydomain/LDAP]
sudo_provider = none
```

---

> This is easily fixed by manually removing sss from that line again. However, each update of the sssd package re-adds that unwanted entry, triggering another flood of mails before we manually remove it again.

An update should not change a configuration file. Configuration files contain specific directives for your system and not for all systems for all users. I would consider that a bug.